# Undefined control sequence when usage of Glossaries and Siunitx

Tags: glossaries, siunitx, glossaries-extra

I'm getting the Error >Undefined control sequence< when I use the command `\si{\ohm}` when defining an entry with `\newglossaryentry{}{}`.

Has one an idea how to fix this problem?

```
% Used Packages
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,symbols,nogroupskip,toc,automake]{glossaries-extra}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

```
% Example Entries
\newglossaryentry{symb:PF}{
    name=\ensuremath{PF},
    description={Power Factor},
    unit={\si{\%}},
    type=symboltype}  % works perfectly

\newglossaryentry{symb:Ron}{
    name=\ensuremath{R_{on}},
    description={Widerstand zwischen Drain und Source},
    unit={\si{\ohm}},  % problematic line
    type=symboltype}  % Error occurs here: Undefined control sequence
```

Comment: you have not shown an example that allows anyone to reproduce the problem, and have not shown your error message (which would say _which_ command is undefined)

Comment: A shot in the dark: the `\si` macro no longer exists in `siunitx`, it's been replaced with `\unit`. Which version of the package are you using?